# Why isn't my new module listed in the list of modules?

Tags: 7

I am trying to build a new module, but, it is not listed in the list of modules.

This is the content of the add_new_chapter.info file:

```
;$Id$

name = Chapters field
description = Will create a field that will refrence a node of type chapter type
package = Online School Development
core = 7.x
files[] = add_new_chapter.module
```

I placed the add_new_chapter.info file in the directory "add_new_chapter" at 
drupalroot/sites/all/modules/add_new_chapter.

what I expect is to see a new category ("Online School Development") in the page listing the modules but it doesn't get listed.

I tried to clear the Drupal cache, but the module didn't get listed too.

Comment: Do you actually have the "add_new_chapter.module" file?

Comment: Hint 1: "; $Id$" is a relict of the CVS days, not necessary. Also, files[] should only be added for files which contain classes and are not loaded on each page anyway (like .module files)

Answer (score 1):

The first things I would check:

1. Permissions settings of the files (chmod - chown)
2. Remove a module to see if it has any effect

Comment: I solved it, simply I needed to clear the catch of the browser too,
but, isn't there a way to force the browser to get a new data every time while I am in the development phase ??

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer and mark it as 'accepted'.  The question you asked in the comment above should be asked on another SE site

Answer (score -1):

Yes, install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and set it to rebuild the theme registry on every page load.

Do **not** forget to turn this off on your production site. It will increase page load times for your users. Use it just for development.